# ExtJS 4.2.1, Internet Explorer 8, dialog stop runnin

Tags: url, internet-explorer-8, extjs4

I am using ExtJS 4.2.1

My application works great with Chrome, but I have to make it work with IE8.
When I load a precise page with IE8 I get the following dialog (my browser is configured in french) :

[image: stop this script]

The question in french is "Stop running this script?"

The page considered contains a treePanel with the url `'stAddAction.do?action=location_tree_selector'` for the proxy.
When I click on no, the script continues to be executed and everything works fine.

The problem is that I don't want that dialog to appear.
When I change the url and set `'stAddAction.do?action=product_tree_selector'` the dialog does not appear (but another tree is loaded). The tree loaded by that url contains less information than the one that makes the dialog appear.

With the url `'stAddAction.do?action=location_tree_selector'` I do not have any problem with Chrome or IE10, only with IE8.
How could I avoid that problem? I guess this is because the tree is too big and it makes time to load it. When I let entirely running this script the tree loads perfectly. But I have to click on the "no" button of the dialog... Is there something I could do?

Thank you

Comment: I found that link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205909-IE-quot-Stop-running-this-script-quot-when-loading-large-store which seems to be the way. I will mention how to proceed if I find anything

Comment: Ok I rectify, paging may be a solution but that is not what I want to do. I just want that "Stop running this script?" dialog to let my tree load in peace

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only option, if I don't want the clients to configure their IE8 browser, is to optimize the code.
I guess that if I can't optimize it enough I will have to refactor.